# Run javascript function for dynamically inserted HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a piece of code that on hover of another element insert's this code below.

```
<div class="star" id="1">
<div class="star" id="2">
<div class="star" id="3">
<div class="star" id="4">
<div class="star" id="5">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

All I want to do is retrieve the ID of each DIV through javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.star').on(function(e){

    e.stopPropagation();
    var rating = $(this).attr('id');

    alert(rating);
});

});
```

I've tried many ways of achieving this, this is the latest I've tried but I'm still having no luck! I'll be grateful of any help

Comment: Freaking easier to just do it next to where the DIVs are inserted. Any reasons why not to do it? Probably I misunderstood you question though

Comment: Agreed, you need to either alter that code, or if that's not possible, then attach another event handler to the hover event of it, and then run the $('.star')... code (perhaps after a slight delay to ensure your code runs after the insert of the divs).

Answer (score 1):

Trigger an event when said divs are added.

```
var counter = 0;
$(someelement).on("mouseenter",function(){
    counter++;
    $('<div class="star" id="' + counter + '" />').appendTo(".star:last").trigger("staradded");
})

$(document).on("staradded",".star",function(e) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Or better yet, skip the event.

```
var counter = 0;
$(someelement).on("mouseenter",function(){
    counter++;
    $('<div class="star" id="' + counter + '" />').appendTo(".star:last");
    alert(counter);
})
```

Comment: This answer should be appropriate if just OP clarifies how it is adding those elements

Answer (score 0):

You have `wrong` syntax of on as you are not `telling` what event you want to bind. After binding your required event e.g. click you can use map function to get all the comma separated ids of `elements` having class `star`.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Exc7s/1/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.star', function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ids = $('.star').map(function() {
        return this.id;
    }).get().join();
    alert(ids);
});
```

You need to use each to iterate through all elements.

```
$('.star').each(function(){           
    var rating = $(this).attr('id');    
    alert(rating);
});

​
```

Comment: But if this code is called before the elements exist (i.e. before the initial 'hover' event that inserts them), this will never get run...

Answer (score 0):

I would use "livequery" plugin - https://github.com/brandonaaron/livequery

If I understood correctly, you need something like old function "live", since you would like to watch all new ".star" elements.

In this case you will just use following code:

```
 $('.star').livequery('click',function(e){});
```

Simple example you can find there - http://jsfiddle.net/WEr5J/11/